# modifiers in Final rendering are different from the render preview

Tags: rendering, modifiers

I have just started learning blender and I am following a tutorial on YouTube. Doing the final rendering, I faced a problem that I have no idea how to fix it.

The first problem I was facing was Boolean objects showing in final render. I made sure that their visibility was off in preview rendering and in object mode, but it still seems to show in the final render. An odd thing that I found was that some Boolean actually didn't show up in the final render while others did. I will add images at the end for better understanding.

The second problem I faced was screw modifier not working properly. It seemed perfectly fine in object mode and even in preview render, but in the final rendering, it definitely looked bizarre.

If you can answer any of this, it will be very appreciated.

here are the images:
[image: preview render]

[image: final rendering]

you could see in the final result (incomplete btw) that few screw modifiers are all messed up as well as Boolean being captured. Boolean on the chocolate(right bottom side of the image) is invisible but those on the cheese is visible.

Comment: It looks like you have a couple of objects hidden in the viewport - hidden objects will still appear in renders. If you want to keep them hidden, move them to a separate collection and then disable (not hide) the collection.

Comment: Look into the Screw and Subdivision modifiers : They have a different setting for Viewport and Render

Answer (score 1):

it seems as I'm going through with the same tutorial series from Crossmind studios as you haha
I got very frustrated by this too, what I found out about the screws was: On the 'Screw Modifier', Check if the number displayed on the "render" option is the exact same as the "viewport steps".
If theses numbers are diferent, it means you are basically telling Blender to put one screw configuration in the viewport, and other on the final render, and that's why it's showing different results.
About the booleans showing up on the final render, click on the little camera right next to the objects on the outliner, this will tell Blender to not show these objects on the final render.

The lesson I took from all of this is: Be more mindful about the difference between what you see on the viewport and what you will render. The guy on the tutorial forgot this, but with a little patience, we can figure things out.
Hope this helped, friend! You're doing just well, don't give up.

Answer (score 0):

Try hide and unhide that particular collection in the outliner and see things which you duplicated.
And delete those which are not necessary for final render.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).